# Registre de "pousser la curiosité"

Tags: expressions, niveau-de-langue

A quel registre appartient l'expression "pousser la curiosité" ?

Ni le TLF ni le dictionnaire de l'Académie Française ne parviennent à m'éclairer sur ce point :

- [Pousser](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pousser)
- [Curiosité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/curiosit%C3%A9)

Certaines [déclarations de personnages publics](http://www.liberation.fr/politiques/2013/07/16/compte-de-cahuzac-en-suisse-taubira-ne-s-est-pas-posee-la-question_918629) comme [certains écrits littéraires](http://books.google.fr/books?id=eiU6AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=%22pousser+la+curiosit%C3%A9%22&source=bl&ots=BKM9Zt1xp0&sig=l_5d_OqDgyBTlezpVBQEXJZrWiY&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=EGzmUfuUJoS4hAevrYCQCw&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=%22pousser%20la%20curiosit%C3%A9%22&f=false) comportent cette expression, mais politiques comme auteurs s'expriment dans différents niveaux de langue.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que cette expression soit liée à un registre en particulier. Elle peut s'employer dans de nombreuses situations différentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Pousser la curiosité" n'est pas une expression en soi.

*Pousser* est utilisé dans le sens II.B.3 du TLF, "*Au fig.* Conduire, développer", qui fait parti du registre courant.

Answer (score 1):

"Pousser" signifie entre autres porter ou étendre une entité, abstraite ou morale, quelle qu'elle soit.

Les auteurs classiques ont écrit :
pousser sa fortune (au sens de destinée), ses pensées, son aversion, ses préventions, sa crainte, sa sincérité, la bonté, la vertu, la faiblesse, ses travaux, ses études, des informations judiciaires, l'outrage, une aventure, sa chance, la chose (au sens de différend), etc..

**Pousser la curiosité est donc d'un très bon registre de langage.**

Comment: « Les auteurs classiques », on aimerait savoir qui.